# How can I use SMTP Amazon SES with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, amazon-ses

I have a Delphi application that sends emails to a smarthost using an Indy IdSMTP object.

I would like to use Amazon SES service, with the SMTP interface. According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html, I need to use a TLS connection.

I'm not sure which value I should use for the IdSMTP object UseTLS property and then what should be specified in IOHandler.

Is there a straightforward way to use Amazon SES in Delphi?  For now I would like to be able to send only text email messages but in the future I might need to send HTML email messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before connecting to the server, you need to assign an SSL-enabled `TIdIOHandler` component, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, to the `TIdSMTP.IOHandler` property, and set the `TIdSMTP.UseEHLO` property to True.  You then have two choices for configuring the TLS settings:

1. set the `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` property to `utUseExplicitTLS`, and then set the `TIdSMTP.Port` property to either 25, 587, or 2587 (all three ports on SES support `utUseExplicitTLS`).
2. set the `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` property to `utUseImplicitTLS`, and then set the `TIdSMTP.Port` property to either 465 or 2465 (both ports on SES support `utUseImplicitTLS`).

The difference between the `UseTLS` values is that `utUseExplicitTLS` will connect to the server initially unencrypted and then send an SMTP `STARTTLS` command to the server to enable encryption when needed, whereas `utUseImplicitTLS` will connect to the server and enable encryption immediately before any SMTP-related data can then be exchanged.

Amazon suggests verifying the server's TLS certificate to verify the integrity of the connection.  You can enable the `sslvrfPeer` and `sslvrfFailIfNoPeerCert` flags in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode` property, and then use the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnVerifyPeer` event to validate the certificate details as needed.